# How do I make bridge-nf-call-iptables change persist across reboot?

Tags: networking, centos

- Centos 7.5

I realise I can change it with:

```
sudo sysctl net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables=1
```

but that does not persist across reboots. How do I make it persist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo 'net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables=1' | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
```